# Node.js error-handle relevance between fs.stat and fs.readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, file-io

First of All, Sorry for my poor English and Thanks for clicking this Question.

I want to read some files with Node.js code

To do so, First, I must check existence of file.

so I used *fs.stat* for that.

and then, I want to read file synchronously.

so I used *fs.readFileSync* for that.

my question is that **Although I handled error for *fs.stat*, Should I error-handle for *fs.readFilesync* seperately ?**

below is code for that

```
  fs.stat('./fooData.json', function(err, stat){
    if(err === null){ // <-- on this point, fooData.json's existence is confirmed.
      try{ // <-- should I error-handle for readFilesync again ?
        let oldData = fs.readFileSync('./fooData.json');
      }
      catch(e){
        console.log(e); // file read error handle
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should because calling `fs.stat` does not guarantee a file existence at the moment of calling `fs.readFileSync` and moreover it does not guarantee that you can read this file at all (no permissions and so on).

The official Node.js documentation does not recommend to use `fs.stat` before `fs.readFileSync`:

> Using fs.stat() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not available.

See [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback)